# Rearranging list elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a `ul li` element function like a `select` input from which user can select a color for the box.

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.color-picker ul.color-list li.active .text').after('<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>');

  $('.color-picker ul.color-list li').click(function() {


    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

      console.log(2);
      $('.color-picker ul.color-list li').show();
    } else {
      console.log(1);

      var color = $(this).find('.box').css('backgroundColor');
      $('.color-picker .color-box').css({
        'background-color': color
      });

      $('.color-picker ul.color-list li.active').removeClass('active');
      $('.color-picker ul.color-list li').hide();

      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.color-picker ul.color-list li.active').show();
      $('.color-picker ul.color-list li .glyphicon').remove();
      $('.color-picker ul.color-list li.active .text').after('<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>');

    }

  });

});
```

```css
.color-picker {
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}
.color-picker .color-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li.active {
  display: block;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li {
  display: none;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li .box {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li.red .box {
  background-color: #c71212;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li.blue .box {
  background-color: #0d89d1;
}
.color-picker ul.color-list li.green .box {
  background-color: #18c771;
}
.color-picker .as-select .select-default {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-picker">

  <div class="color-box">
  </div>

  <div class="as-select">
    <ul class="color-list">
      <li class="red active">
        <span class="box"></span>
        <span class="text">Red</span>
      </li>
      <li class="blue">
        <span class="box"></span>
        <span class="text">Blue</span>
      </li>
      <li class="green">
        <span class="box"></span>
        <span class="text">Green</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jr47ychh/6/)

As you can see the active element remains at the same place.

(Select Blue color and click drop down again)

Is their a way I can make the selected element the first child of the list?

Comment: Use flex-box positioning and set the order of the selected element to be first (see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more info on using flex positioning).  Of course this depends on which browsers you are targetting, but support for flex is now pretty good, >96% according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage **Flexbox** then you don't need to shuffle elements at all. CSS can visually "move" them for you.

```
 .color-picker ul.color-list {
   display: inline-flex;
   margin: 0;
   flex-direction: column;
 }

 .color-picker ul.color-list li {
   list-style: none;
   border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
   padding: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   order:2;
   width: 200px;
 }

 .color-picker ul.color-list li.active {
   display: block;
   order:1;
 }
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/c5Ledt9o/)

Comment: can you tell what does order:2 means? and is this supported in all browsers?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to your questions, caniuse suggests that 96% of browsers support this (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)) but not all.  In particular IE<10 does not support flexbox and IE10,IE11 are a little buggy, however in general I've found this type of thing works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prependTo()` to prepend the `active` `li` element to color picker element.

```
$(this).prependTo('.color-picker ul.color-list');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xq60ok2f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.prepend()` function.

This should work:

```
$('.color-list').prepend($(this));
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0LLnxxmo/)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the current element to the first place of the list with :

```
$('.color-picker ul.color-list').prepend($(this));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ksxhwo43/

Answer (score 0):

The way to make the selected element the first child of the list is detaching the li dom element of the selected item and pre-appending it in the ul dom element.

You are probably going to use:

https://api.jquery.com/detach/

"This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/"

"insert at the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements"